# Should the Data Saver Icon Look like Plus or a Pause?

Tags: mobile-data, data-monitoring, 7.0-nougat, nexus-6p

According to [this page](http://www.androidcentral.com/android-n-gives-you-even-more-ways-save-cellular-data), the data saver icon should look like a pause button.

However, on my nexus 6P (using android nougat), I get a plus icon instead whenever I turn on data saver.
[image]

What does that mean? Am I understanding something wrong? Also, if I keep it on, does the data saver option (no background download, and limited app connectivity) when I am on an unmetered Wi-Fi?

Comment: They might have changed it. The linked article ends with "it's worth remembering that Data Saver may change (or even disappear entirely) between now and the final release."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like Google changed it. According to a video on [this page](https://www.android.com/versions/nougat-7-0/) it should look like a plus sign.

Comment: Thanks. One more question. When I turn on the data saver, does it also affect the traffic with unmetered wi-fi, such as no background update, no automatic loading of images etc.?

Comment: On the same page it says "cell data" so I expect that all background Wi-Fi data  will be unaffected by data saver. (If you use your device as a Wi-Fi hotspot while connected only by cell data, other devices connecting through your phone will be affected)